# How to delete rows for all dates except the last date of the month?

Tags: r, date, delete-row

I'm working with a time series in r which contains daily observations from Nordic Stock Exchanges. I only want to keep the last date of the month for each Company (column).

My data frame, `OSE` looks something like this (but With several thousand rows and columns):

```
Date           Statoil     DNB
1987-09.16     0,21        1,2
1987-09.17     0,22        1,3
1987-09.18     0,15        1,1
1987-09.21     0,16        1,5
1987-09.22     0,27        1,7
1987-09.23     0,28        1,9
1987-09.24     0,30        1,6
1987-09.25     0,32        1,7
1987-09.28     0,29        1,8
1987-09.29     0,33        2,1
1987-09.30     0,34        1,9
1987-10.01     0,37        1,8
1987-10.02     0,38        2,1
1987-10.05     0,34        2,3
1987-10.06     0,28        2,4
1987-10.07     0,27        2,1
1987-10.08     0,25        2,2
1987-10.09     0,21        2,1
1987-10.12     0,31        1,9
1987-10.13     0,31        2,1
1987-10.14     0,32        2,3
1987-10.15     0,37        2,5
1987-10.16     0,41        2,6
1987-10.19     0,51        2,8
1987-10.20     0,62        3,1
1987-10.21     0,59        3,1
1987-10.22     0,58        3,5
1987-10.23     0,61        3,6
1987-10.26     0,62        3,7
1987-10.27     0,63        3,9
1987-10.28     0,57        4,0
1987-10.29     0,54        4,1
1987-10.30     0,64        4,1
1987-11.02     0,66        4,2
1987-11-03     0,67        3,9
```

I would want it to look like this:

```
Date           Statoil     DNB
1987-09.30     0,34        1,9
1987-10.30     0,64        4,1
```

Do you guys have any suggestions for deleting the redundant rows, i.e. the rows that are not the last date of the month?

All efforts to help are much appreciated!

Comment: where is the 'company' column?  `library(data.table); setDT(df1)[, .SD[which.max(as.IDate(Date, "%Y-%m.%d"))] , .(month = month(as.IDate(Date, "%Y-%m.%d")), Company)]`

Comment: @akrun, I may have explained myself a bit confusingly here. Each company has its own column (Statoil is one company, DNB is another, and there are several thousand columns/companies). The numbers in the column for each company is the closing price (numbers used here are just examples).

Comment: Why there is no row of 11th month in the expected outputif it is grouped by month

Comment: We have 30 years of observations, so we should actually end up with 360 rows after the operations. I just added the last dates for each month for the 9th and 10th month as an example. In reality there should also be a row for the 11th month, the 12th month, the 1st month in 1988, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could do the same strategy in the `tidyverse`, grouping on Month and Year:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

tib$Date <- ymd(tib$Date) # parse .$Date to date class

tib %>% arrange(desc(Date)) %>% # order dates last to first
    group_by(month(Date), year(Date)) %>%
    slice(1)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   month(Date), year(Date) [3]
Date Statoil    DNB `month(Date)` `year(Date)`
<date>  <fctr> <fctr>         <dbl>        <dbl>
1 1987-09-30    0,34    1,9             9         1987
2 1987-10-30    0,64    4,1            10         1987
3 1987-11-03    0,67    3,9            11         1987
```

Answer (score 3):

In the example, there is no `Company` column, so it seems like we need to group by 'month' and get the row of `max` Date

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Date := as.IDate(Date, "%Y-%m.%d")]
df1[df1[, .I[which.max(Date)] ,
     .(month = month(Date), year = year(Date))]$V1]
#         Date Statoil DNB
#1: 1987-09-30    0,34 1,9
#2: 1987-10-30    0,64 4,1
#3: 1987-11-03    0,67 3,9
```

Comment: This works to some degree, but not exactly how I want. Now I only get 12 dates (the last date of the month for the past year). I would want it to give me 360 dates (the last date of the month for the past 30 years). Is there a quick fix for this?

Comment: I think you may have edited your answer after my comment? At least I didn't notice the edit before I commented. Anyway, I wasn't trying to bash your answer at all. I'm truly grateful for the time you have taken to answer my question, but Nate's answer worked, and that's the one I tried first. Thus, that's the answer I chose to accept. I also gave your answer an upvote now!

Comment: @VegardDyran  No, I didn't changed the answer after your comment.  May be you commented after I logged off.  I did have an edit earlier - with only 'month' as the grouping variable.  Then, I realized about different years from your comment and changed it.  Anyway, no problem.  Thanks for the comments and have a great dasy!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider converting the dataset to an xts format and then using the to.period() command, which works quickly and easily. For example, let's create a fake daily time series and then subset the last value at each month's end:

```
library(xts)
set.seed(78)
date.a <-seq(as.Date("2000/10/1"), as.Date("2000/12/31"), "days")
dat <-xts(rnorm(length(date.a)), date.a)
dat.month.end <-to.period(dat, period='months', indexAt='lastof', OHLC=F)

dat.month.end
                  [,1]
2000-10-31  1.00117650
2000-11-30 -1.15090619
2000-12-31  0.04944459
```